# In RootViewController my UIBarButtonItem disappears when using UITableViewStyleGrouped

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using a split view for an iPad app.

In my RootViewController.m file I assign two UIBarButtonItems like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 300.0);

// add a save button
saveButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
                        target:self action:@selector(saveAction:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;

// add a cancel button
cancelButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                        target:self action:@selector(cancelAction:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
}
```

These buttons show up nicely when I use UITableViewStylePlain styling for the table view. But if I use UITableViewStyleGrouped, then the buttons disappear. Here is how I set my grouped style

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
return self;
}
```

Regardless of the presence or absence of the buttons, the size of the header remains the same.

I'm clueless as to why this happening.

all help greatly appreciated
Dhoti